# Class diagram representation for C library with Doxygen

Tags: c, class, uml, doxygen, diagram

I am trying to generate a UML class diagram representation of my C libraries (library.c, library.h).
I would like to get a representation containing public (extern) and private (static) functions / variables with the usual '+' and '-' signs, but all I get after enabling all graphs checkboxes in doxywizard is this representation for public structures, not for a certain library.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: from C only the struct / union / enum can be represented in UML in a 'natural' way, and all their attributes are public. Of course you can yourself model a file as a pseudo class and put all global vars as attributes and functions as operations (I do in BoUML) but this is not 'standard' at all

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Please show some code showing the problem (including the images with missing parts).

Comment: I agree with bruno. Pseudo-OO written in C can be recognized by humans. But not (yet) by a machine. You're asking the impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I would like to avoid having to maintain a pseudo-OO code that reflects my acutal C code. I thought this were easily extended also to C, where static functions/variables are private methods/properties, whereas extern functions/variables are public methods/properties. Can you suggest any workaround to achieve this automatic UML class diagram from peudo-OO C generation?